# How filter an object in component with props?

Tags: reactjs, filter, components, key, react-props

I would like to filter and display `onclick` the choice by id in a component by props.
APP COMPONENT: I display the list

```
<div className="App-container">
          <div className="App-container-left">
            <p>Liste des factures</p>
            <div>
              {datas.factures.map((datas) => (
                <>
                  <ul>
                    <li key={datas.id}>
                      N° : {datas.id}|{datas.dateFacture}-{datas.client} -
                      Montant : {datas.montant} €
                    </li>
                    <button onClick={toggleFact} id={datas.id}>
                      Voir
                    </button>
                  </ul>
                </>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="App-container-right">
            {view && <ViewFact obj={datas} selectId={datas.id} />}
          </div>
          <div />
        </div>
```

CHILD COMPONENT: `onclick` I would like display the id

```
export default function ViewFact(props) {
  //filter with id
  const filtered = props.obj.factures.filter((id) => {
    return props.obj.factures.id === id;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div>ViewFact Component</div>

      <div>
        {filtered.map((datas) => (
          <>
            <ul>
              <li key={datas.id}>
                N° : {datas.id}|{datas.dateFacture}-{datas.client} - Montant :{" "}
                {datas.montant} €
              </li>
            </ul>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are exactly asking here .... can you please be more specific and detailed

Comment: what does `toggleFact` do?

Comment: const [view, setView] = useState(false);
  const toggleFact = () => {
    setView(!view);
  };

Comment: toggleFact display or not the view

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to see the clicked item details, so

```
<ViewFact obj={datas} selectId={datas.id} />
```

should has as input only the clicked item. (you need to implement `setCurrentSelectedItem` so as to store the item in your local state)

```
   <button onClick={setCurrentSelectedItem}>
      Voir
   </button>



<ViewFact obj={currentSelectedItem} />
```

and finally your compoment will be

```
export default function ViewFact({ datas }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>ViewFact Component</div>
      <div>
        N° : {datas.id}|{datas.dateFacture}-{datas.client} - Montant :{" "}
        {datas.montant} €
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer !
toogleFact allows to display or not the ViewFact component so with onClick I call the function const toggleFact = () => {
    setView(!view);
  };

on the left I have the list of invoices and like that on the right it allows me to display the corresponding invoice on the right
I don't have a local state, just an object with data

Comment: thought so that's why i proposed this solution.

Comment: I thank you very much for your proposal but I don't have a local state, I just put a js object in a useState. So I can't manage with your solution...

Comment: yes we say the same thing. local state , useState.